# how do i make a setpresence command to trigger it by myself?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im trying to do a set presence command to being able to change presence without restarting my bot and changing my code but im not able to do it, here's my code:

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js")
    const bot = new Discord.Client()
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
    const config = require("./config.json")
    bot.login(config.token)
    
    bot.on("ready", () => {console.log("Loaded up!")});

bot.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    if (command === "set") {

          bot.user.setPresence({
status: "online",
game: {
  name: "a",
  type: "WATCHING"  }})}});
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean without restarting your bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a look at the documentation for discordjs. I can see an example for setting your clientUsers presence while the bot is running.

---

working code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json")

const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Initialized bot, listening...")
});

bot.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
    let [command, ...args] = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(/ +/g);

    if (command === "set") {
        bot.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'with discord.js' }, status: 'idle' });
        return;
    }

    if (command === "ping") {
        message.channel.send("Pong")
        return;
    }
})

bot.login(config.token)
```

---

Documentation Link:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence